# Moto Mocking Calls to AWS DynamoDB Returns Vague Region KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, moto

I am trying to Test a Lambda function handler which calls DynamoDb and works when deployed however in testing Moto seems to have trouble at the setup phase and produces a vague error. The test code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from model.terrestrial import Terrestrial

import pytest
import moto
import boto3
import os
import json

REGION = 'ap-southwest-2'
TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME = 'U_terrestrial'
os.environ['TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME'] = TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME
os.environ['PRIMARY_KEY'] = 'id'

from lambdas import terrestrial_persist_function as func
from tests.lambdas import api_gateway_event

@pytest.fixture
def dynamodb_table():
    with moto.mock_dynamodb2():
        boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=REGION).create_table(
            AttributeDefinitions=[
                {'AttributeName': 'id', 'AttributeType': 'S'}
            ],
            TableName=TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME,
            KeySchema=[{'AttributeName': 'id', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}],
            ProvisionedThroughput={
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 1,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 1,
            },
        )
        yield boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=REGION).Table(TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME)


@pytest.fixture
def mercury():
    file = open('../fixtures/db_2_terrestrial_mercury.json', 'r')
    obj: Terrestrial = Terrestrial.dict_to_object(json.loads(file.read().strip()))
    file.close()
    return obj.dict_dynamodb()


@pytest.fixture
def venus():
    file = open('../fixtures/db_3_terrestrial_venus.json', 'r')
    obj: Terrestrial = Terrestrial.dict_to_object(json.loads(file.read().strip()))
    file.close()
    return obj.dict_dynamodb()


@pytest.fixture
def earth():
    file = open('../fixtures/db_4_0_terrestrial_earth.json', 'r')
    obj: Terrestrial = Terrestrial.dict_to_object(json.loads(file.read().strip()))
    file.close()
    return obj.dict_dynamodb()


@pytest.fixture
def luna():
    file = open('../fixtures/db_4_0_terrestrial_luna.json', 'r')
    obj: Terrestrial = Terrestrial.dict_to_object(json.loads(file.read().strip()))
    file.close()
    return obj.dict_dynamodb()


@pytest.fixture
def mars():
    file = open('../fixtures/db_5_0_terrestrial_mars.json', 'r')
    obj: Terrestrial = Terrestrial.dict_to_object(json.loads(file.read().strip()))
    file.close()
    return obj.dict_dynamodb()


@pytest.fixture
def all_terrestrials(mercury, venus, earth, luna, mars) -> []:

    return [mercury, venus, earth, luna, mars]


def headers():
    return {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "True",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }


def test_get_terrestrials_ok(dynamodb_table, all_terrestrials):
    # given
    print('table: {}'.format(TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME))
    print('os table: {}'.format(os.environ['TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME']))

    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    print("current directory is : " + dirpath)

    with dynamodb_table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for i in all_terrestrials:
            batch.put_item(Item=i)

    # when
    resp = func.handler(
        api_gateway_event(
            '/terrestrial',
            'GET',
            {}
        ), None)

    # then
    assert resp['statusCode'] == 200
    assert resp['headers'] == headers()
    assert resp['body'] == json.dumps(all_terrestrials())


def test_get_terrestrials_empty(dynamodb_table):
    print('table: {}'.format(TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME))

    print('os table: {}'.format(os.environ['TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME']))

    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    print("current directory is : " + dirpath)

    # when
    resp = func.handler(
            api_gateway_event(
                '/terrestrial',
                'GET',
                {}
            ), None)

    # then
    assert resp['statusCode'] == 200
    assert resp['headers'] == headers()
    assert resp['body'] == '[]'


def test_get_terrestrial_ok(dynamodb_table, all_terrestrials):
    print('table: {}'.format(TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME))

    print('os table: {}'.format(os.environ['TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME']))

    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    print("current directory is : " + dirpath)

    with dynamodb_table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for i in all_terrestrials:
            batch.put_item(Item=i)

    # when
    resp = func.handler(
            api_gateway_event(
                '/terrestrial/40743816-c884-4c79-9ab4-6dd4c740c52c',
                'GET',
                {}
            ), None)

    # then
    assert resp['statusCode'] == 200
    assert resp['headers'] == headers()
    assert resp['body'] == json.dumps(earth())


def test_get_terrestrial_not_found(dynamodb_table):
    print('table: {}'.format(TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME))

    print('os table: {}'.format(os.environ['TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME']))

    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    print("current directory is : " + dirpath)

    # when
    resp = func.handler(
            api_gateway_event(
                '/terrestrial/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
                'GET',
                {}
            ), None)

    # then
    assert resp['statusCode'] == 200
    assert resp['headers'] == headers()
    assert resp['body'] == {}
```

The error produced (for each of the tests) is:

```
ERROR [ 25%]
test setup failed
@pytest.fixture
    def dynamodb_table():
        with moto.mock_dynamodb2():
            boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=REGION).create_table(
                AttributeDefinitions=[
                    {'AttributeName': 'id', 'AttributeType': 'S'}
                ],
                TableName=TERRESTRIAL_TABLE_NAME,
                KeySchema=[{'AttributeName': 'id', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}],
                ProvisionedThroughput={
                    'ReadCapacityUnits': 1,
>                   'WriteCapacityUnits': 1,
                },
            )

../lambdas/test_terrestrial_persist_function.py:37: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py:320: in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py:611: in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:102: in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:136: in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:210: in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:356: in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:228: in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:211: in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:183: in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:251: in __call__
    caught_exception)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:269: in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:317: in __call__
    caught_exception)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:223: in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:359: in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:176: in _get_response
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(event_name, request=request)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:356: in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:228: in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:211: in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/core/models.py:292: in __call__
    status, headers, body = response_callback(request, request.url, request.headers)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py:117: in dispatch
    return cls()._dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py:200: in _dispatch
    return self.call_action()
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/core/utils.py:264: in _wrapper
    response = f(*args, **kwargs)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/dynamodb2/responses.py:64: in call_action
    response = getattr(self, endpoint)()
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/dynamodb2/responses.py:108: in create_table
    table = self.dynamodb_backend.create_table(table_name,
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <moto.dynamodb2.responses.DynamoHandler object at 0x122590f50>

    @property
    def dynamodb_backend(self):
        """
        :return: DynamoDB2 Backend
        :rtype: moto.dynamodb2.models.DynamoDBBackend
        """
>       return dynamodb_backends[self.region]
E       KeyError: 'ap-southwest-2'

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moto/dynamodb2/responses.py:56: KeyError
```

In an effort to reduce the wordiness of this question, I have omitted the lambda that I am testing, because I don't believe that we're even getting this far. It looks like Moto is not set up properly. However if you want it, I can provide it in a later edit.

As you can see, the error is quite vague (I hope my question isn't), and I'm not really sure where to start troubleshooting this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

From requirements.txt:

```
pytest==5.1.1
boto3==1.9.66
botocore==1.12.67
moto==1.3.7
```